# Password protect sub-folder of wordpress website on Nginx server

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I am facing a strange problem.
I have enabled password protection on the nginx server for the wp-admin
But once i enable the password protection the php parsing for the wp-admin webpages stop.

Meaning, after i enter the username and password, i can download the php file source code instead of viewing the processed HTML with login screen.

This is my config file
Please tell me what am i doing wrong?

```
server {

    ... server stuff here ..

    # Wordpress Rules
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
         auth_basic "Restricted Access";
         auth_basic_user_file /home/user/domains/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Cache control
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|ttf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
    location ~*  \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }

    # Enable "Vary-Accept-Encoding" headers
    # They are enabled in the nginx.conf
}
```

If I remove password protection, everything works fine, admin panel also works fine. I think I am not adding password block correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to read up on [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

The problem is that the `location ^~ /wp-admin/` block has no way to process PHP files.

This might work, but try using a nested block:

```
location ^~ /wp-admin/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted Access";
    auth_basic_user_file /home/user/domains/.htpasswd;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```